# Unable to copy files from cloned repo in Dockerfile

Tags: git, docker

In my Dockerfile I want to clone some source code and copy all the files/directories from the cloned repo to the file system of the container but I am getting the following error:

> `COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder686077620/my-repo: no such file or directory`

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM ubuntu

ARG GIT_USER
ARG GIT_TOKEN
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN git clone -n https://${GIT_USER}:${GIT_TOKEN}@github.com/<username>/my-repo
COPY my-repo/ /app
```

My build command is: `docker build -t git-test --build-arg GIT_USER=<user>-- build-arg GIT_TOKEN=<token>`

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: By issuing `RUN git clone...` you actually cloned the repo for your image so there is no need to run `COPY`. `COPY` would be needed if you cloned the repo on your host system and wanted to copy it into the image.

Comment: I'd recommend running `git clone` outside the Dockerfile for a couple of reasons.  Try running `docker history` on the image you produced: anyone who has the image now has credentials for your private GitHub repository.  It also is prone to missing updates in the upstream repository (due to layer caching), and as you've written it you can't build non-master branches or changes that haven't been committed yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't the `RUN` command run 'inside' the docker container, while `COPY` tries to copy something from outside to the inside? i.e. if you clone it inside you don't need to `COPY` it. Either directly clone it to where you need it or use something like `RUN mv ...` or `RUN cp my-repo /app/`

Answer (score 1):

Or you might create the directory where you clone

1. `RUN mkdir -p /your/path/ && cd /your/path \
    && git clone <URL>`